# logstash output plugin amazon_es use action update always failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, plugins, logstash

i were using logstash plugin logstash-output-amazon_es to load data to amazon es.
i need to update some index ,but when i use update action , it always report some mistake.
if use action index it works well
my config is look like

```
output {
amazon_es {
    hosts => ["https://search-1111.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
    region => "ap-southeast-1"
    aws_access_key_id => 'xxxxxx'
    aws_secret_access_key => 'xxxxxxxxx'
    index => "test"
    action => "update"
    doc_as_upsert => true
    document_id => "%{requestId}"
}
```

the error is

```
[2020-07-07T10:34:34,645][ERROR][logstash.outputs.amazonelasticsearch][main] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"https://search-11111.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:443/_bulk"}
```

if use postman to post data to es it was workable.

Comment: more detail log of this error `:body=>"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_retry_on_conflict]\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_retry_on_conflict]\"},\"status\":400}"`

Comment: this is a known bug https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/issues/138